# Recommended log monitoring and email notification utilities

Tags: ubuntu, logging

I have an Ubuntu server. What are good tools that monitor my logs and can send me email notifications when errors (or other types of messages) occur? I've heard of [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/files/) and [logcheck](http://logcheck.org/). What are others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been incredibly impressed with [graylog2](http://www.graylog2.com/) It does a decent job. In the slightly older version it was leveraging mongodb to make capped data collections. Now it's moved on to elasticsearch. Pretty cool!

Comment: This quote got me. "Manage your logs in the dark and have lasers going and make it look like you're from space."

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com) also.

Comment: -1 Splunk is crazy expensive, and the basic version is very limited. Caution!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Simple Event Correlator (SEC)](http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/). Pretty steep learning curve. But once you figure it out, you can easily build rules to watch your logs in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in using [LogZilla](http://www.logzilla.pro). It is free for small networks and does everything you need very well.
Full disclosure: I am the creator :-)

Answer (score 0):

logwatch and logcheck run periodically, so these might not be the best choice if you need real-time alerting. There is also log2mail. Syslog-ng and [nxlog](http://nxlog.org) can do real-time alerting based on patterns (disclaimer: I'm affiliated with the latter).